# import urllib.parse fails when Python run from command line

Tags: python, command-line, ipython, python-3.4, attributeerror

I have observed the following behavior in python 3.4.2, and I am unableto explain it. Hopefully someone could shed some light on the matter:

In IPython:

```
In [129]: import urllib

In [130]: print(urllib.parse)
<module 'urllib.parse' from '/Users/ashwin/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/urllib/parse.py'>
```

I've imported a module, and printed one of its attributes. Everything works as expected. So far, life is good.

Now, I do the same thing from the command line:

```
$ python -c 'import urllib; print(urllib.parse)'  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'
```

Say what?! that's not how that's supposed to work.
Ok, maybe this is a python-wide behavior; maybe modules are not immediately imported when using the `-c` flag. Let's try another module:

```
$ python -c 'import datetime; print(datetime.datetime)'
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

What?! How does it work for `datetime` and not for `urllib`? I'm using the same version of python in both places (3.4.2)

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

**EDIT**:

Per one of the comments:

```
$ which -a ipython
/Users/ashwin/.pyenv/shims/ipython
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython
```

And

```
$ which -a python
/Users/ashwin/.pyenv/shims/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: you may want to add the output of `which -a ipython` and `which -a python`

Comment: @cel: I don't understand how that would help, but I've added it

Comment: So `python -m IPython -c 'import datetime; print(datetime.datetime)'` and `python -c 'import datetime; print(datetime.datetime)'` give different results?

Comment: No. `python -c` with `datetime` gives a different result than `python -c` with `urllib`, in that the former throws an `AttributeError` and the latter does not. Yet, the the code with `urllib` does not raise and errors when used within the interactive IPython

Comment: Basically `python  -c 'import urllib; print(urllib.parse)'` and `python -m IPython -c 'import urllib; print(urllib.parse)'` give different results. I see that too. Indeed a very interesting observation. I would add a regular python tag to increase visibility.

Comment: Do you use the same version of python for both of the examples? Using python2 and python3 (reference implementations) I get the same error from command line and from the interpreter. Maybe the `urllib` library isn't the same?

Comment: @skyking: `I'm using the same version of python in both places (3.4.2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `import urllib`, it creates the module object of the `urllib` module (which is actually a [*package*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package)) *without importing its submodules* (parse, request etc.).

You need the parent module object (`urllib`) to be in your namespace if you want to access its submodule using attribute access. In addition to that, that submodule *must* already be loaded (imported). From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules):

> if package `spam` has a submodule `foo`, after importing
>   `spam.foo`, `spam` will have an attribute `foo` which is bound to the
>   submodule. [...] The invariant holding is that if you have
>   `sys.modules['spam']` and `sys.modules['spam.foo']` (as you would
>   after the above import), the latter must appear as the `foo` attribute
>   of the former.

There is only one instance of each module, thus any changes made to the `urllib` module object (stored in `sys.modules['urllib']`) get reflected everywhere.

**You don't import `urllib.parse`, but IPython *does*.** To prove this I'm going to create a startup file:

```
import urllib
print('Running the startup file: ', end='')
try:
    # After importing  'urllib.parse' ANYWHERE,
    # 'urllib' will have the 'parse' attribute.
    # You could also do "import sys; sys.modules['urllib'].parse"
    urllib.parse
except AttributeError:
    print("urllib.parse hasn't been imported yet")
else:
    print('urllib.parse has already been imported')
print('Exiting the startup file.')
```

and launch `ipython`

```
vaultah@base:~$ ipython
Running urllib/parse.py
Running the startup file: urllib.parse has already been imported
Exiting the startup file.
Python 3.6.0a0 (default:089146b8ccc6, Sep 25 2015, 14:16:56) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

It is the side effect of importing `pydoc` during the startup of IPython (`which ipython` is */usr/local/bin/ipython*):

```
/usr/local/bin/ipython, line 7:
  from IPython import start_ipython
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py, line 47:
  from .core.application import Application
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py, line 24:
  from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py, line 28:
  from IPython.core import ultratb
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py, line 90:
  import pydoc
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pydoc.py, line 68:
  import urllib.parse
```

This explains why the below code fails - you only import `urllib` and nothing seems to import `urllib.parse`:

```
$ python -c 'import urllib; print(urllib.parse)'
```

On the other hand, the following command works because `datetime.datetime` is *not* a module. It's a class that gets imported during `import datetime`.

```
$ python -c 'import datetime; print(datetime.datetime)'
```

Comment: But if I try `pydoc` in IPython I get a `NameError`. Does that not mean that `pydoc` has not been imported by IPython at startup?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget it *has* been imported, you can check if it's already in [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules): `'pydoc' in sys.modules` returns `True`. You just have to import it in the current namespace.

Comment: Ok, but `urllib` isn't in the current namespace OR in `sys.modules` in IPython. So I'm still not clear on how `urllib.parse` automagically exists in the namespace

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I'm not so sure... Running `[x for x in sys.modules if 'urllib' in x]` from IPython, produces `['urllib.parse', 'urllib']`. When `import urllib.parse` is executed, Python will check if it can skip creating a module object by looking into `sys.modules`. When the module object is ready, it'll be put in the local namespace under the name you chose (e.g. using the `import` statement). Note that namespaces are not shared.

Comment: But I don't try `import urllib.parse` in IPython. I try `import urllib` and then call `urllib.parse.unquote` without any further imports

Comment: [*"For example, if package `spam` has a submodule `foo`, after importing `spam.foo`, `spam` will have an attribute `foo` which is bound to the submodule. \[...\] The invariant holding is that if you have `sys.modules['spam']` and `sys.modules['spam.foo']` (as you would after the above import), the latter must appear as the foo attribute of the former."*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules) @inspectorG4dget

Answer (score 3):

`urllib.parse` is available from Python 3 onwards. I think you might need to `import urllib.parse`, not `import urllib`. Not sure if (when) submodule import is implicit.

I would guess IPython imports `urllib.parse` on startup and that is why it is available.

`parse` is a module not an attribute:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 15 2014, 22:01:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.parse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse
<module 'urllib.parse' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/parse.py'>
```

Comment: Your analysis seems incorrect, as I am using python3.4.2 even when I call `python` from the command line. As seen in my paths, the first entry is from `pyenv`, which is currently pointing to v3.4.2

Comment: Try `import urllib.parse` instead of `import urllib` as suggested.

Comment: Also thank you for the path clarification. I updated the question and removed the bits which were incorrect.

Comment: IPython does not import `urllib.parse` on startup. I know this because I setup the IPython startup imports myself. But you're right in that running this in the interactive shell also does not work as expected. I have a feeling that IPython resolves this by creating an invisible `import urllib.parse` to avoid this error