# Module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request' error when run from batch file, but works fine from IDE

Tags: python, batch-file, urllib

I get the exception "module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'" when I run my program via a bat file, but it works fine when I run it in the Spyder IDE.  I'm running Python v3.7.  What could be the difference?  I want to run it via the batch file.

Batch file:

```
@echo off
@python c:\users\gadkins\documents\pythonscripts\dl_unzip.py %*
@pause
```

py file snippet:

```
import urllib
import smtplib
import ssl

url_src = 'https://site.edu//uploads/tmp/_Files0805-21Oct2019.zip'
url_dst = 'D:\download\af.zip'
uzip_src = url_dst
uzip_dst = r'D:\data\af'
data_type = 'af'

try:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_src, url_dst)
except Exception as e: 
    error = str(e)
    print(error)
    print(study + ': ' + data_type + ' download failed!')
    print('Exception = ' + error)

    #if email == '-e':
    msg('dl_fail', study, data_type, '', error)

    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolution.  I updated my code to `import urllib.request` which seems to not only import the package, but also the `request` submodule.  However, I'm still unclear as to why this is needed when executing via the command line, but not with Spyder and Jupyter.

This post seems to summarize the answer best:

[import urllib.parse fails when Python run from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33206536/import-urllib-parse-fails-when-python-run-from-command-line)